# What do I do if my Recepisse is about to expire and I still haven't received my carte de sejour?

Tags: visa, resident-permit, france

My *récipissé* is about to expire in two weeks but I still haven't received my carte de séjour. Is there any way to check the status online? I applied from Paris (Cité) and I haven't had any response. Or if I call them what number should I contact them on?

Comment: Considering the urgency of the situation I'd directly visit the Prefecture to get an update.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any way to check the status of your application online. It might be worth trying but I wouldn't expect too much from a call either. In all likelihood, a decision hasn't been made yet. You will hear about it whenever there is a decision but that doesn't solve your immediate problem.

Meanwhile, you are supposed to show up/make an appointment (depending on the *préfecture*) to renew the *récipissé*. It's very frustrating and is supposed to be exceptional but in practice it does happen a lot.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if I have to take all my documents again to get it renewed?